# IP based public addressing system

Tags: networking, voip, audio-streaming

We are trying to create an IP based PA system for my institution. Our first hunch is to use an asterisk server with clients in auto-answer mode. Is there any better method, or a more apt open source framework?
Our internal network is fiber backboned with mostly *nix systems.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start looking at an [RWALL](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/rwall1.html) command as a framework and instead of text send audio files.

Conversely you can have a very simple multicast server and client that does exactly the same thing.

Security would be your biggest concern since both approaches are inherently insecure.